# Hard copy of array with instance of class within object

Tags: javascript, class, object

I am creating a simple game with multiple levels. Each level is represented by object of key-value pairs. Inside each level there is also array with new instances of class that will be loaded inside the level. So far it worked fine but when i implemented restart button program cannot load thoose instances again because i already changed them. So i need to hard copy thoose instances into level and when you press restart button you can just hard copy them again.

This is an example of my level object.

```
const level4 ={
 width:window.innerWidth,
 height:window.innerHeight,
 gates:[new Gate(canvas.width-20, 100,0,-2), new Gate(200, 15,4,-1)],
 blocks:[new Block(50,100,0, 0, 50, 1, 2), new Block(200,200,0, 0, 50, 1, 1)],
 difficulty:'easy',
 id:4
};
```

I already try to hard copy object with this parse function but it doesnt work.

```
const parseLevel = (currentLevel) =>{
  return {
    width: currentLevel.width,
    height: currentLevel.height,
    gates: parseObjects(currentLevel.gates),
    blocks: parseObjects(currentLevel.blocks),
    difficulty: currentLevel.difficulty,
    id: currentLevel.id
  };
};

const parseObjects = (array) =>{
  let newArray = [];
  for(let i of array){
  let newObj = Object.assign( Object.create( Object.getPrototypeOf(i)),i);
  newArray.push(newObj);
  }
return newArray;
};
```

And in my function where I am loading the level I call:

```
 level = parseLevel(level4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simple solution is to convert your `level4` from a constant to a function. That way you could call it multiple times and always get a fresh instance.

```
const level4 = () => ({
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  gates:[
    new Gate(canvas.width-20, 100,0,-2), 
    new Gate(200, 15,4,-1)
  ],
  blocks:[
    new Block(50,100,0, 0, 50, 1, 2), 
    new Block(200,200,0, 0, 50, 1, 1)
  ],
  difficulty: 'easy',
  id: 4
});
```

Comment: I spend last hour to fix all issues when i rewirte my level as function but its working. Awsome thank you man.

Answer (score 2):

have a look [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089)

I don't know how your `Gate` and `Block` objects are structured internally. They may have nested objects that fail in getting hard copied.

```js
var k = {"a": "b", "c": {"d": "c"}};
var j = Object.assign( Object.create( Object.getPrototypeOf(k)),k);

console.log(j === k)
// false

console.log(k.c === j.c)
// true
```

per the article:

one simple option would be `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`. This can be pretty slow.

The library [lodash](https://lodash.com/) also has a `cloneDeep` function that might be faster. I don't have any benchmarks though.

Comment: I cant use JSON cause of methods that my class has. Structure of class is few atrributes and methods.